# Logic to create common Serverlet3 Login

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf

I am using Servlet3 Login to Authenticate User in website I have these Login

1. Website Normal Login(Fill the Sigup form)
2. Facebook Login (From Facebook Id)
3. Twitter Login (From Twitter)

And I am already authenticate user by below code

```
 HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
       request.login(username, password);
```

And it is working fine for Website Login as user gave his/her EMailId and password and it store in DB.

Now I modified table and added more columns to save Facebookid in same user table and also password for Facebook login FacebookId work as a Password as well. Same I will do for Twitter But I want the same Servlet3 to authenticate user. How can I achieve  it?

And also added `context.xml` file inside `META-INF` folder

```
<Realm localDataSource="true" debug="99"
    className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" connectionName="user"
    connectionPassword="password" connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ ccc"
    digest="md5" driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" roleNameCol="role_name"
    userCredCol="password" userNameCol="email_id"
    userRoleTable="users_list" userTable="user_list_view" />
```

Also it is possible to check which query fired by realm entry?

Comment: Probably a better fit for SO

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't lump the various auth factors into a single auth table

What you're trying to achieve is not possible with the vanilla realm configuration. What you want is the [Combined Realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#CombinedRealm) available in tomcat.

The `CombinedRealm` gives you the flexibility to configure multiple datasources as auth sources.

Given that flexibility, you should be able to have a separate tables `facebook_auth` and `twitter_auth` and more. Adding more columns to the same table for a possibly growing number of auth sources is unsustainable.

Comment: But here user_list_view is a database view which get all details for a user ..Can it is possible to get what query run by relm entry of tomcat

Comment: @subodh- not that I'm aware of. Obviously it's just going to select the username and verify the password. What do you need the query for? It's not like you're going to be able to change it or that it's a complex query.